# Как прочитать элемент объекта NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Есть объект:

```
NSTextField *outText = "Текст";
```

Как проверить второй элемент строки, как это было в C++:

```
if(outText[1] == ‘е'){
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добраться до второго символа можно так (пишу всё одной строкой, хотя нужно разбить для читаемости и для проверки, что там в строке действительно есть второй символ):

```
if ([[[outText stringValue] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,1)] isEqualToString:@"e"]) {
    // ...
}
```

Я сам не проверил, но должно работать.

Comment: может быть [outText text]?

Comment: Это NSTextField, а не UITextField, немного другая история...

Comment: Это работает. Тут как я понял, сначала строка уменьшается до диапазона (1, 1), а потом эта строка сравнивается с "e". Неужели все так сложно, учитывая даже то, что мы переходим к классу NSString? У этого класса нет других способов? Или это мне как начинающему программисту в Objective-C так кажется?

Comment: Нашел в классе NSString метод characterAtIndex, который позволяет читать символ по индексу. Теперь код можно упростить так:
if([outText stringValue] characterAtIndex:1 == 'e']){
//...
}

Comment: Я конкретно с `characterAtIndex` сам не работал и писал ответ на скорую руку. Конечно, `characterAtIndex`, короче. Всё верно.